# bs4 срейпинг текста согласно тегу

Tags: pandas, beautiful-soup, bs4, web-scraping

Из двух столбцов HTML странички нужно:

1. Выковырять текст только зеленого цвета.
2. Если текст не зелёный, а чёрный, то вместо значение оставить NaN.
3. Сохранить все эти значения в pandas датафрейм.

Пример HTML таблицы (сорри, что в екселе):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат, который я хочу получить в конечном датафрейме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

cons_df = pd.DataFrame()
data = []

with open("test.html", encoding='utf-8') as html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") #заранее взята страница из таблицами
    table = soup.select('font[color="#00875a"]') #выбор по зеленому цвету (текст, который мне нужно скрепить находится только под этим тегом "font[color"
for i in range(0,len(table)):
    rows = [table[i].get_text()]
    data.append(rows)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['mix']) #датафрейм только с зелеными значениями

df['mix'] = df['mix'].str.strip()

#мне нужно было каким-то образом разделить стринги от дат и я решил выфильтровать их с помощью startswith:

val_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

str_val = df[df.mix.str.startswith(tuple(val_list))]
dates = df[~df.mix.str.startswith(tuple(val_list))]

str_val = str_val.reset_index(drop=True)
dates = dates.reset_index(drop=True)

cons_df = pd.concat([cons_df, str_val, dates], axis=1)
```

Код вроде работает нормально, но мне нужно дописать часть, которая бы оставляла NaN вместо черных значений. С этим кодом в результате я получаю вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что я нашел по этому поводу в гугле, но никак не могу переписать под себя:

```
A function for BeautifulSoup in Python that returns the text of the first tag if it exists, or an empty string if not. Useful for web scraping where empty string NaNs are desired. This function is one I use a lot for scraping projects, but it is likely something you should modify for your own needs.

Parameters: soup-> the bs4 soup item, tag_class-> the class of the desired tag (optional), return_text-> should the function return the text of the item if possible or the item itself(?).
def get_text_if_exists(soup, tag, tag_class=None, return_text=True):
    if tag_class:
        item = soup.find(tag, {"class":tag_class})
    else:
        item = soup.find(tag)
    if item and return_text:
        return item.text
    elif item:
        return item
    return ""
```

[update]

test.html:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таких проектов как на скрине приблизительно 50-60, но у всех одинаковая структура.

html код таблицы:

```
<div class="table-wrap">
<table class="confluenceTable"><tbody>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd"><b>1column</b></td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><b>2column</b></td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><b>3column</b></td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><b>4column</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">1A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST1</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>15-Jul-2022 6 PM CET</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">2A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;TEST2</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">3A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST3</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">4A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST4</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>15-Jul-2022 6 PM CET</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">5A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;TEST5</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">6A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST6</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>15-Jul-2022 6 PM CET</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">7A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;TEST7</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">8A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">9A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">10A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST8</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">11A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">12A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">16A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">17A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: a test.html посмотреть можно?

Comment: @СергейШ да, добавил скриншот. если нужно будет то могу вам скинуть его файлом

Comment: Ну и как я по ващему скормлю скриншот BeautifulSoup? Саи написать HTML-структуру по скриншоту?

Comment: @СергейШ добавил html код таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="table-wrap">
<table class="confluenceTable"><tbody>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd"><b>1column</b></td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><b>2column</b></td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><b>3column</b></td>
<td class="confluenceTd"><b>4column</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">1A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST1</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>15-Jul-2022 6 PM CET</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">2A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;TEST2</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">3A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST3</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">4A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST4</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>15-Jul-2022 6 PM CET</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">5A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;TEST5</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">6A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST6</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>15-Jul-2022 6 PM CET</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">7A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;TEST7</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">8A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">10A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>TEST8</b></font></td>
<td class="confluenceTd">18 July 2022 1 PM CET</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd">11A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('tr')[1:]
data = [[y for y in v.find_all('td')[1:-1]] for v in table]
data = [[x, y] for x, y in data if x.text.strip() and y.text.strip()]
data = [[z.text.strip() if z.find('font') else 'NaN' for z in c] for c in data]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['TEST', 'DATA'])
print(df)

    TEST                  DATA
0  TEST1  15-Jul-2022 6 PM CET
1    NaN                   NaN
2  TEST3                   NaN
3  TEST4  15-Jul-2022 6 PM CET
4    NaN                   NaN
5  TEST6  15-Jul-2022 6 PM CET
6    NaN                   NaN
7  TEST8                   NaN
```

Comment: Спасибо вам хороший человек